# Can I separate a Gif in each image is conformed?

Tags: png, gif, animated-gif

I was wondering if there is any tool or if there is any way in order to take from a gif file, and save a file for each image.

This way I can get each frame separated in a file.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gifapp/

Comment: ImageMagick will do it: "convert input.gif +adjoin frame%03d.gif"

Comment: Awesome @GlennRanders-Pehrson I did not know about this, I was using image magick trough grunt-responsive-images Thanks. I will give it a try.

Comment: It's a little trickier if the GIF has been "optimized" to update only the changed part of the image from frame to frame.  ImageMagick (or GraphicsMagick) can deal with that, too, with the "-coalesce" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using python

A script made in python is available [here](https://gist.github.com/revolunet/848913):

```
import os
from PIL import Image


def extractFrames(inGif, outFolder):
    frame = Image.open(inGif)
    nframes = 0
    while frame:
        frame.save( '%s/%s-%s.gif' % (outFolder, os.path.basename(inGif), nframes ) , 'GIF')
        nframes += 1
        try:
            frame.seek( nframes )
        except EOFError:
            break;
    return True


extractFrames('ban_ccccccccccc.gif', 'output')
```

`ban_ccccccccccc.gif` is the name of your `GIF` image, and `output` the name of the folder were the frames will be saved.